# How do I run Android tests with largeHeap="true"?

Tags: android, testing, heap-memory, android-largeheap

We have a customer app made for tablets and we need more than the regular heap, so our app defines the largeHeap="true" attribute for the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.  This works fine.

However, when we run tests on a device using android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner and 
android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 we get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when we try to use more than the standard heap.

We have tried setting largeHeap="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml of the test project as well as in the app project.

Running the tests on an emulator with a large heap size configured works.  The setting increases the general max heap size, not the limit for largeHeap.  This is a workaround, but we would like to run the tests on actual devices also.

Is there a way to run the tests on a device with a large heap?